# SwiftUI truncates text for some letters

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have create below view in SwiftUI. It works fine for some words but for some words of same length it truncates the text, Please see the image below. I am using Xcode 11.6

```
var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Text("John") //Problem with this line if I change text to "Aohn"/"aohn" it is truncating text.
            .font(.title)
            .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
        HStack {
             Text("Regular")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                
             Text("Medium")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
   
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix - use fixed size. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
VStack {
    Text("aohn").fixedSize()    // << here !!
```

Comment: why do we need to add fixedSize() ?, is it SwiftUI Defect?

Comment: I can answer *how*, sometimes... all *why* are to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com or https://developer.apple.com/forums/